# In Hinduism, are you not supposed to be happy?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, upanishads

From what I'm gathering, you are not supposed to be "bad" obviously, but it also seems that you are not supposed to be "happy" either?

Am I getting this right?

[edit] Are we to exist without karma, akarma, so be neither good nor bad?

Comment: Where did you get that idea?

Comment: Exactly. How did you arrive at hat conclusion

Comment: I'm heading out to the dentist, I will edit and explain when I return.

Comment: Gave a very brief explanation before leaving.

Comment: I am not sure why you got this thought. To me, this question makes no sense and also edit. Please try to explain clearly..

Comment: Vedanta says that we are above pain as well as pleasure, happiness as well as suffering. Does this mean that they do not want us to be happy? NO. What is important here is the emphasis on the temporariness of worldly happiness. Real happiness lies in moving beyond bodily pleasures and worldly pleasures. Having great money can give us happiness for twenty years maybe, but what after that? Hinduism wants us to question what it is that makes us truly happy - beyond the apparent.

Comment: @Sai please put this as an answer. It was exactly what I wanted to know. I understand now that it meant happiness & sadness in relation to the materialistic or worldly things, because they create bondage to materialism or worldly things. Not that you can't be happy spiritually, which manly comes from devotion to god.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not like that. The sole purpose of Hinduism is to show the path of true happiness to all beings. It's because happiness is the inherent desire of every *jiva* and until and unless one *jiva* becomes truly happy he will be doing various kinds of activities, good and bad and getting entangled by their reactions.

It is just that the definition of happiness is something different in Hinduism:

> *yo vai bhuma tat sukham, nalpe sukham asti, bhumaiva sukham, bhuma tveva vijijnasitavya iti, bhumanam, bagavah, vijijnasa iti.* [Chg. Up. - 7.23.1]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Happiness is infinite, there is no happiness in finite. Happiness is completeness, happiness is the totality, happiness is in the Absolute.

**Real happiness is something, upon which sorrow and distress cannot take over**. That which wanes away is not happiness. Everything material being under the influence of time is certain to perish at some point, so happiness that is dependent upon material things, positions and qualities are certain to cause distress upon their loss. So Vedanta school of thought from Hinduism teaches to fix the mind upon God who is imperishable and eternal, hence by doing so the happiness that will be derived will also be eternal.

Now the other thing is, bliss is probably the suitable word to express that state of happiness . Bliss is superior and beyond happiness and distress. So the scripture states that state of saintliness and  serenity is achieved by him who neither delights on happiness nor gets agitated in distress:

> *duḥkheṣv anudvigna-manāḥ sukheṣu vigata-spṛhaḥ
>
>   vīta-rāga-bhaya-krodhaḥ sthita-dhīr munir ucyate* [BG - 2.56]
>
> **Meaning**
>   One who is not disturbed in mind even amidst the distress and miseries or elated when there is happiness, and who is free from attachment, fear and anger, is called a sage of steady mind.

Happiness is the core concept of Hinduism and that's why it prescribes all the rules and regulations. Because happiness is the natural outcome of *dharma* (right actions). There is a beautiful verse regarding this but I don't know where it's from. It is as below:

> सुखं वांछति सर्वो हि तच्च धर्मसमुद्भवं
>   तस्माद्धर्मः सदा कार्यः सर्ववर्णेः प्रयत्नतः
>
> **Meaning**
>   Everyone desires Happiness and that arises only from *dharma*. Hence, *dharma* (right action) should always be the duty and endeavour of all.

Comment: The quote at the end reminds me of a quote from the Apology of Socrates: "I tell you that virtue is not given by money, but that from virtue comes money and every other good of man, public as well as private."

Answer (score 2):

The goal is eternal happiness.

**Eternal Happiness**

> Yudhisthira said,’… Even thus, endued with actions, creatures come
>   into this wheel of life that is continually turning like the wheel of
>   a car, and even thus, coming thither, they meet with their
>   fellow-creatures. **He, however, who abandons the worldly course of
>   life,** which is really a fleeting illusion although it looks eternal,
>   and which is afflicted by birth, death, decrepitude, disease, and
>   pain, **is sure to obtain happiness**. When again, the very gods fall
>   down from heaven and great Rishis from their respective positions of
>   eminence who, that is acquainted with truths of causes (and effects)
>   would wish to have even heavenly prosperity? ..... Reflecting on these
>   circumstances, this nectar of wisdom hath come to me. Having attained
>   it, I desire to get a permanent, eternal, and unchangeable place (for
>   myself). Always (conducting myself) with such wisdom and acting in
>   this way, I shall, by betaking myself to that fearless path of life,
>   terminate this physical frame that is subject to birth, death,
>   decrepitude, disease, and pain.

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section IX