# What if you felt God wanted you to create something materialistic, which leads to a life of bondage, how does one recover from that?

Tags: belief

Just as the title says. If a person feels there purpose in life is to create something materialistic, such as scriptures that help others find there way, but at the same time the person feels like they are in bondage because of it, especially when it is a life long quest. How does one recover from that?

In Hinduism it seems even though the person feels they are serving God, at the same time that person is condemning himself.

Comment: Could please clarify the question a little.. What are you trying to create? How do you "feel" this is your purpose? How can it feel like "bondage" and that it is your "purpose" at the same time? And why do you say that person feels that they are serving God, but also condeming himself? This seems to be several questions put into one without much explanation

Comment: I don't know how to explain it any better. Serving God by creating scriptures and such, which are materialistic, which creates good karma actually, but we must be without karma to not be in bondage, or acquire true happiness, or to be at one with God.

Comment: If God wants you to create it, then you do it as ordained without attachment either to the task or the results. By practising nishkama karma yoga, one can avoid karma sticking to their jeevas.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I revived the question because this is a possible original of "[I want to ask about creating your own reality, manifesting your wishes/desires, and attracting a certain outcome](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18980/i-want-to-ask-about-creating-your-own-reality-manifesting-your-wishes-desires)" That was stuck in review for more than 3 days. It is a possible duplicate of this question. The title of mentioned question is unclear and the body matches with this question.

Comment: @SreeCharan OK. @ OP- However, we must remember to perform only dharmic karmas. Not adharmic ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr;

1. Until and unless one has realised God and obtained true happiness, whatever he will do he will do it only for the sake of happiness of himself and not others (even if the reward is intrinsic like seeing others happy). So any kind of work done in that phase may feel like a bondage for the person because he is missing the real purpose.
2. Karma is created when there is mental attachment to it and its results. Without mental attachment and feelings of doership karma will not bind.
3. Work done for God without any personal motives is always liberating.

---

I understand how you feel with this. But I'll have to explain few things first, please bear with me:

First of all, God would not want anything from anyone. It is because, only he who lacks something will want that thing from somebody or somewhere else. But for God there is nothing that is lacking and unachievable :

> *na me pārthāsti kartavyaṁ triṣu lokeṣu kiñcana nānavāptam avāptavyaṁ* [BG - 3.22]
>   - O son of Pṛthā, there is no work prescribed for Me within all the three planetary systems. Nor am I in want of anything, nor have I a need to obtain anything.

So if a common person like us who is not spiritually advanced feels that God wants him to do something, then it's only his delusion. I know most of us feel it from time to time that may be God wants me to do this, may be this is the purpose of my life, but these are only our subconscious thoughts. It is not God who wants us to do it, it is only us who want to do it driven by our nature and predispositions of the mind. Which are arising due to effect of our past karma. We only add the excuse of God to back it up.

If God wanted someone to do anything, then the person would have no fussy feelings about it, rather solid confirmation from God through some divine means (like visions, dreams, etc.). That is, God would tell the person directly through some means like he told Arjuna in Mahabharata that through him He wants to kill the evil Kauravas:

> *mayaivaite nihatāḥ pūrvam eva
>
>   nimitta-mātraṁ bhava savya-sācin* [BG - 11.33]
>   - They are already put to death by My arrangement, and you, O Savyasācī, can be but an instrument in the ﬁght.

Now it is true that people who have wrong notions or biased views may think God is subconsciously saying him to do a thing, but that's never God, that's always the subconscious mind. How? Because, if it were God, then you could ask Him a diffucult question (like what's the mass of planet Mars) the answer of which you don't know and he would reply back the correct answer. But that hardly happens. So now we are settled on the point that it is usually the subconscious mind, not the almighty omniscient God that influences a person to do some work.

Now secondly, if for whatever reason a person gets the desire to do some noble work for God like writing a scripture and doesn't have selfish motives, then that work will not bind him. Because work done for the purpose of God is always liberating and its not material:

> *mad-artham api karmāṇi kurvan siddhim avāpsyasi* [BG - 12.10]
>   -  By working for Me you will come to the perfect stage.
>
> *mat-karma-kṛn mat-paramo mad-bhaktaḥ saṅga-varjitaḥ
>
>   nirvairaḥ sarva-bhūteṣu yaḥ sa mām eti pāṇḍava* [BG - 11.55]
>
> **Meaning**
>   My dear Arjuna, he who engages in My pure devotional service, free from the contaminations of fruitive activities and mental speculation, he who works for Me, who makes Me the supreme goal of his life, and who is friendly to every living being – he certainly comes to Me.

But one should be careful that such work doesn't produce pride or egoism in him, else tainted by material qualities that work can cause attachment due to the feeling of doership. Mostly when any work is done for the purpose of God, the work and its results,whether good or bad, are always offered to the God. That's why even materialistic work done for God doesn't bind the doer. So **mental renunciation is important**. The mental renunciation of action (physical  renunciation not necessary) becomes *karma yoga*, and any such work whether it is done for or against God does't bind a person. That is the path of without worship I tried to explain briefly in the [other answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2992).

So if anyone is condemning himself due to the noble work because he is missing out many other things in life and finds himself in bondage due to it, then it's only his lack of understanding. Choices has to be made in life and once done with proper understanding there shouldn't be any feelings of bondage or remorse. And when it comes to doing works related to God without selfish motives, then it is just natural that the person will find himself lacking materially, but he would be happy and peaceful in the mind. I tried to explain it briefly, but if you need more scriptural references or explanation feel free to comment and I'll add them when I get time.

Comment: please help me with this http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/power-of-the-religion-existence-of-god-evil-its-structure-defined-in-holy-books

Comment: Please don't answer questions liable to be closed.