# Power of the religion,Existence of God-Evil,its structure defined in holy books,Hinduism to define

Tags: shiva, worship, guru-geetha

I am hindu,a believer in hinduism,but respect each and every religion equally....somedays ago I was having discussion about The Gods Goddessess with my friend after which i was left with no answer.....I want to regain my believe in religion and answer my friend to tell him the power of hinduism,

---

> **The Discussion:**

*I was on the side of the religion and my friend was against it...My questions are the same as of asked by my friend that left me silent...*

> **Me :**  God Exists !,How can you say that he is nowhere.Who created this
>   world then, have you not heard about jiva and maya etc. etc.
>
> **My Friend:** O really! Where is he then?
>
> **Me :** He is all Over
>
> **My Friend:** Man! seriously,you are saying this, I can't believe I am
>   hearing this from a professional like you living in 2014.
>
> **Me:** Its nothing to relate this thing with professionalism.
>
> **My Friend :**  Ok so tell me
>
> - **If the Gods are real**,where are they?
> - Bhrama,Vishnu,Mahesh, **were they having body structures like humans?**    if yes then how can they be God(they are Not avatars
>     either)
> - **They were having wives** like normal human males do, and they were termed as Goddessess.How were they different from humans
> - Mahesh(Shiv) smoked weed.Really a God?
> - What's **karma,punar janma**,do you really believe in them?Who is taking them into account?The murders happening.the rapes
>     happening,the betrayals.
> - There are **so many religions**,with their own boundaries and    restrictions,completely different from each other,how can you know
>     which one to believe.
>
> **All these are bookish**,they are created by the great writers to
>   maintain rules in the past. to make the people fear of the power they
>   can't see,and follow the civilization ,that's all  And those
>   people(the Gods if exists) were the best of there times and
>   great scientists; not more than that.

---

On hearing all this I was left with silence,please provide me with the answer,please........ **Looking forward for responses that will help me to regain my beliefs in religion.** Because now I am ARGUING WITH MYSELF about my beliefs.....WAS I A dumb following it?

**IF something positive exists, then this is sure that negative exists too, i.e the evil, the power opposite to God** ..

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16927/discussion-on-question-by-divide-by-zero-power-of-the-religion-existence-of-god).

Comment: Study Hindu philosophies

Comment: @Ajay can you share if any?

Comment: I have not studied anything, just I am going to start, but I know only one thing, Nyaya school of thought says "some people live in misery, while others don't at the same time because of their past life deeds.. This is the proof of existence of god"

Comment: @Ajay still it's no proof, it's a belief with no evidence

Comment: no evidence?  The same thing is also happening today

Comment: You can also show him these peoples https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nayanars

Comment: just read about sankhya darshan(which is patanjali's yoga darshan minus God). Also remember that sankhya darshan was promoted by Krishna too in gita. It is spiritual philosophy without God, or you can read about Theravada buddhism, it has no God

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being you, I would provide him and answer, he could understand:

1. According to quantum physics, there must be an observer to make something to exist. Without an observer, world would be an infinite ocean of possibilities, no matter.
2. It is accepted that our universe started with a Big Bang, but who was that observer that made the first impulse, that allowed matter to emerge from that infinite ocean? Wouldn't you call such entity a God?

---

As the question has been altered: There should have been the same amount of matter and anti-matter created and the two should have anihilated again on contant. Yet, there happens to be matter. This leads us to conclusion, that there must have been more matter than anti-matter. ***Is the balance really so strict to be equal? How about infinity - infinity = ?***

I won't help you with Hinduism much, to me all this is an attempt to describe something beyond our comprehention in words, we could understand - a metaphore. How far it goes I cannot tell.

---

***This part will rather be personal***, something I feel, something I have seen in my vision: There was an entity asking himself the very first question: Who am I? (Bible, Exodus 3.14: "I am who I am" or simply "I am". [So-ham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soham_%28Sanskrit%29) = "I am He/That"). That entity got overwhelmed with Love to all that has to come - The Creation. *(That is quite hard to describe what all I could see and feel, that was me who got overwhelmed.)* That was so called Big Bang. ...some would say, that such God would have desires and therefore would not be a God. We are. What is the difference between pure love and desire? I believe there is no problem in it, but you may find one-step-longer explanation in Hinduism, I don't think it is that important.

**We are perfect in an infinite time line**. We are not perfect when we thing about ourselves as only a part of what we really are. ***It is evolution... but what is time?***

Comment: Was it a positive power....? If yes, then there must be something negative too according to the balance defined in nature...The evil ?a power opposite to God

Comment: Why there is matter at all if there should be the same ammount of anti-matter and the two should have annihilated again in the infinite ocean of energy or possibilities? It seems, that some *balances* are not that perfect. And a question of good and evil is far more complicated. I would say that God created us of pure Love. Why are we *imperfect*? Are we? We can learn, have fun, love... and with incarnations, imagine what future may bring. Look in the past, was the world *more evil*? What is the direction?

Comment: Is someone taking our good deeds bad deeds into account...really?

Comment: Nicely annotated......looking forward for more responses to get my belief back

Comment: That is the part when believes come in to play. I am no God to tell, never seen the being enforcing karmic rules. For me, it is energy - every action has its *color* which attractes energy of *similar color*. Time-line is really big. Some actions happen immediately, some later.

Comment: you have mentioned the very good points regarding the observer and matter-antimatter imbalance. And regarding time, in Hinduism God is eternal time Himself [*aham evākṣayaḥ kālo*](http://vedabase.com/en/bg/10/33).