# What is the meaning of Life if all is pre-written or controlled by the will of God?

Tags: gods, moksha, life

Assumptions:

1. God is the supreme
2. Everything that we do is the will of God which may or maynot have an effect on the future
3. Our purpose in life is to submit to God, Do good deeds, acquire punya
4. In the end our final destination is to become one with God because we are all parts of the supreme soul which is God

So My Questions are:

1. Why does God bother to run all this drama?
2. What is the point in putting these parts of the soul through all this hardships and happiness on Earth when all is just a big Drama and some time down the line all these souls ultimately attain assumption 4.
3. If a person realises the above assumptions what is the point of him living here on Earth. Why should he go through this thing called Life?

One Question in the bigger sense:

1. Why does God bother to do all this? He can do whatever he wants. Isn't it pointless for him? Isn't it like God is a little lonely kid with all the toys(The earth, the people, the happenings) just playing with them?

Comment: Answer would be KARMA. See this http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/3500 and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2989/3500 . i suggest you to read answers of @jabahar (Be happy) on karma. They are very informative. See questions under tag"karma". You get basic idea of karma. Doubts you have are already answered on this site. Just read as many questions as possible.

Comment: nice question.... this is what i was also thinking about the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise, nothing happens without will of Bhagwan. But that doesn't stop us from doing what we want.

This might not be an appropriate example but for the lack of a better one I am using it. The power of almighty is like an electric current. As long as you have a proper supply you can do whatever you want with it. You could run a fan, tube-lights, TV, computers, refrigerators, power plants, cars, the list goes on. How we use it is up to us. One can also use it to electrocute someone. If the pwoer supply is cut, all electrical appliances will stop functioning.

Similarly, it is God who empowers us to do stuff. If he pulls his power back, the entire universe will come to a stand still. It'll decay. How one uses his power is completely one's own decision. He does give us wisdom about how to live life, what is right and what is wrong. That's how we are different from puppets. That's how life is different from a drama. It is because of this power we call him all-doer. Without his will, our minds can't even generate a fragment of thought let alone doing something. (mad-bhayad vati vato 'yam. suryas tapati mad-bhayat - Bhagwad Gita)

God wouldn't stop a terrorist from killing an innocent child, neither will he stop a soldier from killing a terrorist. It is up to the individual to decide where to fire. It is our deeds which make us who we are. (More details on KARMA theory, Bhagwad Gita)

Bhagwan Swaminarayan has written in his Shikshapatri that "One should not commit suidcide." Why would he write that if he wouldn't have granted enough liberty to an individual to end his \ her own life?

And finally about assumption 4, it is not lying in the dirt for the taking. It take years (lives) of devotion to attain. Manushya deh is the only form where one can work towards attaining oneness with Brahma.

Food for thought - 
If God wanted to play with us like toys, one earth is more than enough for him. (7 billion homo-sapiens + other countless species) Why would he create infinite universes, each with countless earth like planets?

Thousands of years ago, our Rishis could precisely calculate \ measure and document a lot of things (like Earth's diameter, constellations etc.)  which science has only found recently or yet to find. If you read scripture like Gita, Vachanamrut, you'll experience that a lot of it precisely going on in our lives, body and mind. So what they have written about God stands more than 50% chance of being the truth. Don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

God gave you brain, and then its God's will is that "All people should have **free will** and they will bear the fruit of their karma choices made as per their will "
(Hence, God's will and your own free will are both simultaneously possible)
(free will to do karma and reap the fruit of their karma)

---

When their cumulative bad actions of their free will creates havoc/imbalance more than a certain point, then only God returns to restore balance.

ref: Bhagavad Gita Chapter 4, Verse 7-8

> यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत । 
>   अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं सृजाम्यहम् ॥४-७॥
>   परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् । 
>   धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥४-८॥

---

Then later again God's will is that everybody should have free will.