# Why do we rely on god so much?

Tags: gods, prayer, teaching

This question for me is a confusion.
Why do we rely on god to get good grades, money or good life? 
Logically if I have worked hard to earn, I will earn. The only reason that I would talk to god is because of mental satisfaction. I would talk to him not to ask but seek peace and clear my head of anything that disturbs me.

My parents/relatives always say "Pray to god and all will be good" I ask myself why is this? is this misconception or reality?

If I have an exam coming up and I decide "OK, I will pray to god every day till the exam and I should be fine" This surely will not work. So why is it that we have so much reliance on god? why cant we deal with things like an adult and not cry like babies to god and blame or question him on why this has happened?

Please do not be offended. I am 16 and still in the loose end on my religion. I truly hope there is a god because it satisfies me thinking that there is one divine spirit with me at all times.

Comment: Because that is easiest way to get **Dharmic** things done quickly, only if your devotion is **sincere** (observe words in bold).

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. Because to do Dharmic things you do not rely on god, it is at your will. However I mentioned in my question, what if you want something? why do you go to god rather than trying yourself?

Comment: Good question. Keep asking yourself the same and more 'What is happiness?' .. 'What exactly is a good life?' .. 'What do I do with good grades and money?' .. 'What use do they have when I become old?' and browse some of the posts here such as [Is the ultimate purpose of life only to serve God?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2989/2995) and [Why does God allow us to suffer?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6855/2995)

Comment: This is to inculcate in your mind that you are created by God and as per his wish only you can act. Again it goes back to karmic theory. Fully surrender to God and realise the bliss.