# Are there explicit statements in the scriptures about the purpose of human life?

Tags: scripture, life

[Some suggest](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/is-the-ultimate-purpose-of-life-only-to-serve-god) the purpose of human life is happiness, but no references to explicit statements in the scriptures were provided.

Are there **explicit** statements about the purpose of human life in the scriptures?

Comment: Purpose of life or propose of human life?

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore I meant human life, but now you got me curious!

Comment: Haha @Sparkler you can ask about the purpose of life as a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the Mrigendra āgama the purpose of **human** life is mentioned.

> atha dehādi sāpekṣaṁ tatpumartha prasādhakam| 
>                                      tato niyati sāpekṣamastu karma niyāmakam|| 
>                                             So, if it is maintained that karma itself is capable of accomplishing **all the four goals of human life - [dharma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma), [artha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artha), [kāmā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama) and [moksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha)** – for the souls depending on body, instruments and others, then that karma is to be held as depending on niyati tattva also. So, it is niyati tattva that is responsible for the regulation and restraint of the karmic fruits.  Chapter 10, verse 16,17.

Moreover first three goals are said to be **inferior** by the same āgama, these 3 are just to accomplish last goal because one can't attain moksha without exhausting previous Samskars.

> mastrivargavāmatvāt rahasyañca  svabhāvataḥ|| 
>                                                  vāmaṁ dhāma paraṁ guhyaṁ yasyāsau vāmaguhyakaḥ| ,
>                     Since the three goals – dharma, artha and kama – **are of inferior nature when compared to the highest state of liberation(moksha)**, they are collectively known as ‘vama’. That effulgence(deva) of Siva which enables the souls experience dharma, artha and kama according to their karmic fruits becomes known as  ‘vama deva’. Since, by its own nature, it remains very subtle and secret(guhya, not exposed to vision), the ‘Vamadeva’ mantra is considered to constitute the privy part of the form of Lord Siva (vamadeva guhya) Chapter 3, verse 12,13.

**Purpose of human life in Chandogya Upanishad is said to be Moksha.** -

> Higher than the immense self is the unmanifest;
>    Higher than the unmanifest is the person;
>    Higher than the person there’s nothing at all. 
>   That is **the goal**, that’s the highest state. CU. Valli 3, verse 10.

**Lord Krishna seems to reiterate this in BG as well**-

> This unmanifested state is called the Indestructible. They call that the **highest goal** which, having obtained, they return not. That is My highest abode. BG.Ch 18, verse 21.

**EDIT:**- From [this](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1181901391942378/permalink/1231995163599667/) link, I have found a beautiful verse.

> सोपानभूतं मोक्षस्य मानुष्यं प्राप्य दुर्लभम् | 
>   यस्तारयति नात्मानं तस्मात् पापतरोत्र कः || 
>   ततश्चाप्युत्तमं जन्म लब्ध्वा चेन्द्रियसौष्ठवम् | 
>   न वेत्तात्महितं यस्तु स भवेदात्मघातकः || 
>   Who is the greater sinner than the one who, having found an elusive human embodiment close to liberation, does not save himself? 
>   He who, having found this best birth, does not [apply] the efforts of the senses, does not comprehend the good of the soul, he is the murderer of the Atman.
>   (कौलावलीनिर्णय, प्रथम उल्लासः / Kaulavalinirnya Tantra, the first chapter, Shloka 31-32)

Comment: भवेदात्मघातकः does not imply "murderer of the Atman" but merely indicating harm, Atma cannot be destroyed. Humans who do not behave like human but reflect animalistic qualities get demoted and have to endure billions of years of suffering all over again till the time they again accumulate enough merits for a Human Birth.

Comment: @Harsh where is the proof for that?

Answer (score 0):

Dharma, Artha (wealth), kama (Desire) and Moksha (liberation from the endless cycle of Samsara) are the four goals of life.

**Purpose of human life**

> Dharma, understood as the Supreme Good of man, can never have wealth
>   as its reward. Nor has wealth, understood as an aid to the achievement
>   of Dharma, been conceived as an aid for the attainment of kama
>   (desire). Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence in sexual
>   pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to make life
>   unbroken. **And as for life, it has the quest of the Supreme Truth as
>   its end – not certainly Karma (i.e. performance of rituals and social
>   duties) for the attainment of wealth (prosperity here and heaven
>   hereafter).**

***Srimad Bhagavata Purana I.2.9-10***

Comment: "Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence in sexual pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to make life unbroken" what is meant by this sentence?

Comment: It means that you are allowed to have sex for procreation but not simply for pleasure.