# What is the purpose of personal life if one inevitably winds up undoing his carma and personality to merge with the absolute?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita

The purpose of life according to most hindu and vedic traditions is liberation from rebirth. But ultimately this just seems like going back to square one in every sense.
How is it possible then that beings like Krishna and Rama have been born and reborn despite being fully realised and free from carma.

Most hindu people live life with a goal of not living again. This seems extremely contradictory in every way especially also in the light of bhagavad gita where the main instruction is to live life and act  without pertaining to the fruit of action. But freedom from rebirth and merging with the absolute is again a fruit of action one can be attached to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there explicit statements in the scriptures about the purpose of human life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18159/are-there-explicit-statements-in-the-scriptures-about-the-purpose-of-human-life)

Comment: "How is it possible then that beings like Krishna and Rama have been born and reborn despite being fully realised and free from carma." This is called a paradox and has not been solved om Hinduism. Such conumdrums occur a lot in Hinduism and other religions.

Comment: Lol that's not an explanation..