# What is the origin and meaning of this verse?

Tags: tantra

Kaulavalinirnya Tantra,

> सोपानभूतं मोक्षस्य मानुष्यं प्राप्य दुर्लभम् |
>   यस्तारयति नात्मानं तस्मात् पापतरोऽत्र कः ||
>
> ततश्चाप्युत्तमं जन्म लब्ध्वा चेन्द्रियसौष्ठवम् |
>   न वेत्तात्महितं यस्तु स भवेदात्मघातकः ||
>
> Who is the greater sinner than the one who, having found an elusive human embodiment close to liberation, does not save himself? He who, having found this best birth, does not [apply] the efforts of the senses, does not comprehend the good of the soul, he is the murderer of the Atman.

(कौलावलीनिर्णय, प्रथम उल्लासः / Kaulavalinirnya Tantra, the first chapter, Shloka 31-32)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18159/3869)

Comment: You already have mentioned meaning and origin of the verse. Are you looking for some commentary for better clarity? If So, please update in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there explicit statements in the scriptures about the purpose of human life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18159/are-there-explicit-statements-in-the-scriptures-about-the-purpose-of-human-life)