# What is the purpose of life? Is it all about being happy or being useful to others?

Tags: life, birth

I mean come on, we are born and we die. So what is the purpose of life?

Comment: No human being can become happy unless he/she is useful to others unless one leaves the society or is out of his senses:)

Comment: Related or a duplicate [Is the ultimate purpose of life only to serve God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2989/5212)

Comment: I think the purpose of life as a human is to try and never be born again.

Comment: The purpose is to get moksha because the material world is full of suffering.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, that is only one of the 4 purposes or purushartha - dharma, artha, kama, moksha.

Comment: I dont remember marking it as duplicate. I marked it as opinion based.

Comment: @ram what is your source? Dharma isn't a goal. It is a means to get moksha.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, are you serious, you have not heard of [purushartha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puru%E1%B9%A3%C4%81rtha) ?

Comment: @ram purushartha means act like man not lady

Comment: @PratikCJoshi, purusha refers to atma, not man or woman.

Comment: @ram but is it wrong : https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=hi&tl=en&text=purusha

Comment: @PratikCJoshi, do you realize one word can have [more than one meaning](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=purusha&direct=au)

Comment: @ram in your link it says that Moksha is the ultimate goal so I think we are done then.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, of course, it is the ultimate goal. who is arguing that ? but it is not the only goal/purpose.

Comment: @ram yes I agree.

Answer (score 3):

[Ramakrishna mission](https://belurmath.org/ideology) sums it up best:

> आत्मनो मोक्षार्थं जगद्धिताय च
>
> Atmano mokshartham jagad-hitaya cha

For one’s own salvation **AND** for welfare of world