# Is our life only for Bhakti of God?

Tags: bhakti

Is there anywhere explictly written that the purpose of our life is only Bhakti of God and nothing else.

I have heard it is writen in some scripture (I think Garbha Upandishad) that when a child is in the womb , it keeps praying to god to take him out of it and in return he will devote his whole life towards bhakti of god but after coming out of the womb , maya surrounds him and he forgets his promise.
This indicates our life's only purpose is bhakti of god.
Also **who has written this Garbha Upanishad** ? Is it written by Ved Vyas ?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/is-the-ultimate-purpose-of-life-only-to-serve-god